# Reset the numbering sequence for all "entryno" attributes after deleting an entry

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, datagridview, increment

The application writes entries to an xml document - working as a database - being these entries displayed as rows in a datagridview. Each "entry" node has its "entryno" attribute. Each time an entry is deleted this "entryno" numbering sequence is broken.
I was able to implement the code to incremente the "entryno" for each new entry created but have been stuck for a good while trying the above.

```
private void Deletbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//entry[@entryno='" +     Dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value + "']");

        try
        {
            if (node != null && Dgv.CurrentRow.Selected == true)
            {
                doc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(node);

                // Trying to refresh the sequence each time an node is deleted.
                int Attrno = int.Parse(doc.SelectSingleNode("//entry[@entryno]").Value);
                do
                {
                    Attrno = 0;
                    Attrno++;
                } while (Attrno < doc.ChildNodes.Count);
                doc.SelectSingleNode("//entry[@entryno]").InnerText = Attrno.ToString();

                doc.Save(Application.StartupPath + @"\SleepRecords.xml");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Click the left side of the grid to select a row to delete.", "Select row", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        ReloadData();
        Resetbtn_Click(Deletbtn, e);
        makePdf();
    }
```

FYI, this is how I increment the "entryno" attribute on each new entry created (just the relevant piece of code).

```
                XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//entry");
            int max = 0;
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                int nodeAttr = int.Parse(node.Attributes["entryno"].Value);
                max = nodeAttr;
            }
            max++;
```

The Xml Document that stores entry data. The datagridview draws information from here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- These are the entries -->
<entries>
  <entry entryno="1">
    <weekday>Saturday</weekday>
    <date>16/12/2017</date>
    <time>21:42</time>
    <action>Out of bed</action>
    <mind>Ok</mind>
    <body>Ok</body>
  </entry>
  <entry entryno="2">
    <weekday>Sunday</weekday>
    <date>17/12/2017</date>
    <time>02:56</time>
    <action>Awake in bed</action>
    <mind>Ok</mind>
    <body>Ok</body>
  </entry>
  <entry entryno="3">
    <weekday>Sunday</weekday>
    <date>17/12/2017</date>
    <time>03:07</time>
    <action>Awakening</action>
    <mind>Ok</mind>
    <body>Ok</body>
  </entry>
  <entry entryno="4">
    <weekday>Sunday</weekday>
    <date>17/12/2017</date>
    <time>03:18</time>
    <action>Awakening</action>
    <mind>Ok</mind>
    <body>Ok</body>
  </entry>
  <entry entryno="5">
    <weekday>Sunday</weekday>
    <date>17/12/2017</date>
    <time>03:38</time>
    <action>Out of bed</action>
    <mind>Ok</mind>
    <body>Ok</body>
  </entry>
</entries>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            int count = 1;
            foreach (XElement entry in doc.Descendants("entry"))
            {
                entry.SetAttributeValue("entryno", count++);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement your solution in the Deletebtn_Click event but without success, even after parsing the "entryno" string attribute value to the count integer. Hopefully it is clear that the code needs to convert all of the "entryno" attributes strings to integers, before it can iterate through them to increment that integer count and then return a string value (re-convert to string) of that iteration for each attribute. The attribute string must be parsed before you can increment the resulting integer, and then re-converted to a string to be allocated as an attribute value. TY.

Comment: I was complicating what needn't be complicated. Your solution was correct. Thanks.